# tkinter - Attach scrollbar to widget for Text Adventure

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm relatively new to Python and coding in general, so I'm a bit rubbish with most of the terminology. 
I've researched this myself but I'm still relatively unsure (kept messing up), so hope someone can help me.

I'm looking to attach the scrollbar within my code to the right side of the text widget, rather than having it floating around the bottom corner.

My project is a text adventure (learning Python along to a book), and I have been building a very basic GUI to house the game. Essentially the text box here is placeholder, and it'll be replaced with the game code down the line, with graphics making up the rest of the window surrounding the center text/command prompt. I'm assuming doing this would be doable relatively easily?

I'm happy to work out just how to sort the scrollbar currently, as it's helping me learn!

Thanks guys!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("GAME TITLE")
mainframe = Frame(root, width=720, height=540)
mainframe.pack()

gametext = Text(root, width=75, height=15)
gametext.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=gametext.yview)
gametext.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

gametext.tag_configure('fonttype1', font = ('Arial', '12', 'bold'))
quote = """GAMEPLAY TEXT HERE"""
gametext.insert(END, quote, 'fonttype1')

root.mainloop()
```

[Sample Screenshot of code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyXbj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If all you're using is a text widget and scrollbar, use `pack` for both. `place` is best used very, very rarely.

```
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
gametext.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

Comment: @BrianOakley I had used 'place' so that I could have the text widget a certain size within the middle of the window, with (currently) blank space around it.
Using 'pack' on both does join them together, so I can find another way to place the text box the way I want to.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GordjScott: you're free to use `place`, but if you plan to use other widgets around the edges, `place` will make that much more difficult than if you use `pack` or `grid`.